# sublime text ruby .erb block comment keyboard shortcut?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext2

I'm looking for a shortcut in sublime text 2 that will make a block comment in a .erb file.

For instance say I have this block of code in my .erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <p>my code</p>
<% end %>
```

And I want to quickly comment out the whole thing like:

```
<% 
=begin %> 
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <p>my code</p>
<% end %>
<% 
=end %>
```

Is there a way to highlight that chunk and hit a keyboard shortcut to add those comment blocks? I've tried highlighting the block then choosing Edit > Comment > Toggle Comment and Edit > Comment > Toggle Block Comment but nothing happens.

I have the ERB Insert and Toggle Commands package installed but maybe I need something else?

Answer (score 2):

The usual Sublime keyboard shortcut to comment/uncomment a selection is `cmd-/`, and block comment is `cmd-opt-/`, but these would have the same effect as Edit > Comment > Toggle Comment, so if that isn't working, they probably won't either. 
I've tried using these in an .erb template, and not only does it work, it seems to be pretty good about using ruby comments for interpolated segments, and html comments for the rest.

Comment: Hmm for some reason I only get HTML comments when doing this. Maybe you have a .erb package installed that I don't that takes care of this? I have ERB Insert and Toggle Commands installed, but I don't think that covers comments.

Comment: It also doesn't work for me. cmd + / in an `.html.erb` file simply prepends a `#` to the start of the line

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac I comment out a block of code by selecting the text and hitting command and / at the same time.  Another useful one that I recently learned is if you need to indent several lines or take our something from several lines, hold down option and select the lines to you want to adjust.

Comment: Cmd-/ gives me an HTML comment, not the ruby block comments.

Comment: Theres an html.erb file that will put out html comments and then the .rb file will put out ruby's comments. While in the html.erb, It looks like you have to only select the ruby code to just have the ruby commented out, otherwise it will comment out all of it, but not correctly comment out the ruby in <%= %>.  Also in the bottom right hand corner you can select which programming language it is using.  For the html.erb file it should says HTML (RAILS) and for the rb file it should say Ruby on Rails.